# Inconclusive second derivative test

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am struggling with this problem:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be $C^3$ and the second derivative $d^2$$f(y)$ = 0 at a critical point y but one of the third partial derivatives (may be mixed) of f != 0 at y.

Prove that y is not a local minimum or maximum.

I'm not really sure how to start on this problem and haven't been able to come up with a formal explanation.  I'm thinking that if you approach y along the axis that makes the third partial != 0, there must be a change of sign for a second partial derivative, and so the first derivative on one side of y is negative and is positive on the other side in a certain direction.

Any help with this would be appreciated, thanks!